# Openerp change the action of top menu Human Resources

Tags: odoo, menuitem

I need to change the action for the default Human resources menu.

when I am clicking on the "human Resources Menu" it is going to Employee menu on left side, but I need to go to leave requests directly. how can I do that?

some one suggested me change sequence number but I did not know how to do that, please help me to do this.

see the following picture  to see in detail.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change in two file and replace with below tag given.

- **addons / hr / hr_view.xml**

  ```
  <menuitem id="menu_hr_main" parent="menu_hr_root" name="Human Resources" sequence="20"/>
  ```
- **addons / hr_holidays / hr_holidays_view.xml**

  ```
  <menuitem name="Leaves" parent="hr.menu_hr_root" id="menu_open_ask_holidays" sequence="0"/>
  ```

Hope this will give you as your require output.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open leave request first, then you have to pur leave request as first positon in Human Resource menu, by default openerp first open the first menu[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `menuitem` `sequence="1"` number and later update the module.Here,

```
<menuitem id="menu_hr_main" parent="menu_hr_root" name="Human Resources" sequence="3"/>
```